# Citation-Style-Language (CSL): Missing indentation of second line in docx and odt output

Tags: r-markdown, pandoc, bookdown, csl, pandoc-citeproc

*RMarkdown* generates a nice bibliography with `pandoc` (using the `citeproc` option) via *LaTeX*, where the second line is aligned to the second field (i.e. after the number of the citation) like in

```
1. Long title of
   the first citation
```

However, when generating output in *docx* (or *odt*) format the second line is not aligned to the second field of the first line despite using the `second-field-align="flush"` option in my CSL file:

```
1. Long title of
the first citation
```

The important part of my CSL file looks like this:

```
  <bibliography et-al-min="6" et-al-use-first="1" second-field-align="flush" entry-spacing="0" line-spacing="2">
    <layout suffix=".">
      <text variable="citation-number" suffix="."/>
      <group delimiter=" ">
        <text macro="author" suffix="."/>
        <text macro="title" suffix="."/>
        <choose>
          <if type="chapter paper-conference" match="any">
            <text term="in"/>
          </if>
        </choose>
        <text macro="container-title"/>
        <text macro="editor"/>
        <text macro="volume"/>
        <text variable="page"/>
        <text macro="issuance"/>
        <text macro="access"/>
      </group>
    </layout>
  </bibliography>
```

Which additional diagnostics could I run to figure out why the `second-field-align="flush"` tag ignored for the *docx* (*odt*) output?

Besides, I would interested in a way to decrease the indentation after the citation number.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this issue does not seem to be resolved yet.
This has been discussed in [the pandoc discussion board](https://groups.google.com/g/pandoc-discuss/c/ikiIkHKlTUs) and previous [pandoc-citeproc maintainers have fixed it](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-citeproc/issues/29#issuecomment-707105366) but the issue may be resurrected after pandoc moves from pandoc-citeproc to [citeproc](https://github.com/jgm/citeproc).